# GSL linkage on Windows

Tags: c++, c, cmake, linker-errors, gsl

I am trying to compile examples from GSL documentation. Windows, Cmake + MSVS + GSL 2.6 installed under conda.

Basic example gets compiled and works just fine:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(test)

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)

add_executable(test)
target_sources(test PRIVATE main.cpp)
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE "${GSL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
target_link_libraries(test "${GSL_LIBRARIES}")
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>

int main (void)
{
    double x = 5.0;
    double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
    printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

But [this one](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/ode-initval.html) fails with a linkage error:

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>

int
func (double t, const double y[], double f[],
      void *params)
{
    (void)(t); /* avoid unused parameter warning */
    double mu = *(double *)params;
    f[0] = y[1];
    f[1] = -y[0] - mu*y[1]*(y[0]*y[0] - 1);
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

int
jac (double t, const double y[], double *dfdy,
     double dfdt[], void *params)
{
    (void)(t); /* avoid unused parameter warning */
    double mu = *(double *)params;
    gsl_matrix_view dfdy_mat
            = gsl_matrix_view_array (dfdy, 2, 2);
    gsl_matrix * m = &dfdy_mat.matrix;
    gsl_matrix_set (m, 0, 0, 0.0);
    gsl_matrix_set (m, 0, 1, 1.0);
    gsl_matrix_set (m, 1, 0, -2.0*mu*y[0]*y[1] - 1.0);
    gsl_matrix_set (m, 1, 1, -mu*(y[0]*y[0] - 1.0));
    dfdt[0] = 0.0;
    dfdt[1] = 0.0;
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

int
main (void)
{
    double mu = 10;
    gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {func, jac, 2, &mu};

    gsl_odeiv2_driver * d =
            gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys, gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd,
                                           1e-6, 1e-6, 0.0);
    int i;
    double t = 0.0, t1 = 100.0;
    double y[2] = { 1.0, 0.0 };

    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        double ti = i * t1 / 100.0;
        int status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply (d, &t, ti, y);

        if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf ("error, return value=%d\n", status);
            break;
        }

        printf ("%.5e %.5e %.5e\n", t, y[0], y[1]);
    }

    gsl_odeiv2_driver_free (d);
    return 0;
}
```

`gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd` is defined somewhere in GSL like this:
`GSL_VAR const gsl_odeiv2_step_type *gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd;`, where `GSL_VAR` means extern.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

you need re-compile the gsl source codes using vcpkg .
vcpkg can compile gsl automatically with CMake. Please google vcpkg. it is very easy and no mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Binary compatibility of the GSL and your application must be the same: only Win64 buld GSL library project can be used with Win64 your application (or Win32 GSL library with Win32 application, respectively), also build your project and GSL in one mode (Debug/Release) and one compiler.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26422999)

Comment: I fixed my answer