# A problem to link GSL on Windows with CMake : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol gsl_root_fdfsolver_newton

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, linker-errors, gsl

I want to use the [**GSL**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/index.html) (https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/index.html) and in particular the newton method. But I have on windows an error that I don't have on Linux :

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol **gsl_root_fdfsolver_newton**

I use ***GSL 2.6*** that was installed with ***miniconda*** on my computer. I build the project with ***CMake***.

My project has the following structure :

- Blade/

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - application/

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - main.cpp

I use **CMake** to link the library. Here are the two CMakeListst.txt files I wrote :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)

project(projBlade)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)   


if(MSVC)
    add_compile_options(/W4)
endif()

#gsl
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")
    set(GSL_ROOT_DIR "~/miniconda3/envs/blade/")    
endif()

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)    


add_subdirectory(application)
```

and the second CMakeLists.txt in the folder *application/* :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)

project(projApplication)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(SRCS
main.cpp
)

set(HDRS
)

add_executable(blade ${SRCS})

set_target_properties(blade PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX )

target_compile_features(blade PUBLIC cxx_std_17)

target_link_libraries(blade GSL::gsl GSL::gslcblas)

install(TARGETS blade 
RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

Here is the *main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
#include <gsl/gsl_roots.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
}

int main()
{
    

    const gsl_root_fdfsolver_type *solver_type{gsl_root_fdfsolver_newton};
    gsl_root_fdfsolver * solver{gsl_root_fdfsolver_alloc(solver_type)};   
    gsl_root_fdfsolver_free(solver);

    return 0;
}
```

I add that I have already used the GSL for numerical integration without any problem but it seems that the problem comes from the gsl variable **gsl_root_fdfsolver_newton**

When I compile this code on *Linux* with *gcc* it works but the compilation fails on *Windows* with *msvc*.

It would be nice if someone has a clue on how to solve my problem.

My problem seems similar to [GSL linkage on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438874/gsl-linkage-on-windows)

Comment: Are you sure it's supported on Windows? GNU products often aren't, or only grudgingly.

Comment: @john Yes I am. I installed the library by using _miniconda_ package manager